# Replace Derivative[ i ][ f ][ t ] with f[ i, t]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

Assume the `PadeApproximant` is carried over `f[t0] * g[t0]` with the order `{1, 1}`, that is

```
PadeApproximant[f[t0] g[t0], {t0, t, {1, 1}}] // FullSimplify
```

The result gives me `f`, `g` and their derivatives.
The question is: How can I convert the `Derivative[i][f][t]`, `Derivative[i][g][t]` to `f[i,t0]` and `g[i,t0]` with `i = 0, 1, 2`?

Comment: Could you include an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: `expr /. {Derivative[i_][h_][t_] :> h[i, t], h_[t_]:> h[0, t]}`?

Comment: it works, Thanks Michael. I did try your first part of the replacement, so it did not give me the result I want